# Windows 7 + Ubuntu on Zenbook UX32VD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I bought a Zenbook UX32VD the other day, and I upgraded it with a 256GB SSD and 8GB RAM. I installed Windows 7 on the SSD, and partitioned it so there was 40GB for Ubuntu and the rest for Windows. Then I formatted the iSSD that is soldered on there so I could use that as a space for shared files.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on the 40GB partition with a live USB, but I cannot boot into Ubuntu. The regular screen with options on it doesn't show up; it just boots straight into Windows. I've read lots of posts on the problem with Ubuntu on a Zenbook, but none where they have my problems.

Below is a picture of the partition manager that shows that Ubuntu is installed.
Has anyone experienced this before?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because I installed Windows 7 without UEFI, so I reinstalled it under UEFI and installed Ubuntu under UEFI as well. All is good now!

Comment: Please, accept this answer. It is completely acceptable to answel own answer.